# A function that can take timestamp from user as input and convert it into a total number of seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, timestamp

I've been trying to write a script that would accept a text as a timestamp from the user, convert it to a total number of seconds, and then start a timer. For example

```
Time: 1h:1m:30s
>> 3690s
```

I've come up with this solution for taking the timestamp from the user

```py
def toSecond(timestring):
    t = 0
    remove_space = lambda str: str.replace(" ", "")
    timestring = remove_space(timestring)

    try:
        if (":") in timestring:
            time = timestring.split(":")
            try:
                for i in time:
                    if i[-1] in ("s", "S" "M", "m", "h", "H") and i[0].isnumeric():
                        if i[-1] in ("h", "H"):
                            t += int(i[:-1]) * 3600
                        elif i[-1] in ("m", "M"):
                            t += int(i[:-1]) * 60
                        else:
                            t += int(i[:-1])
                    else:
                        print("No num or no char Provided")
            except IndexError:
                print("nothing provided")
        else:
            if (
                timestring[-1] in ("s", "S" "M", "m", "h", "H")
                and timestring[0].isnumeric()
            ):
                if timestring[-1] in ("h", "H"):
                    t += int(timestring[:-1]) * 3600
                elif timestring[-1] in ("m", "M"):
                    t += int(timestring[:-1]) * 60
                else:
                    t += int(timestring[:-1])

            elif timestring.isnumeric():
                t += int(timestring)

            else:
                print("No time Provided")
    except ValueError:
        print("Error Value")

    return t
```

This solution is working, However, I was wondering how can I do this more shorter and more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the hours, minutes and seconds and then use `datetime.timedelta` like this:

```py
from datetime import timedelta

ts = "1h:1m:30s"
time_indicators = ["H", "h", "M", "m", "S", "s"]
for ind in time_indicators:
    ts = ts.replace(ind, "")

hours, minutes, seconds = ts.split(":")
print(timedelta(hours=int(hours), minutes=int(minutes), seconds=int(seconds)).total_seconds())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch bad user input - using split then a regex:

```
import re

UNIT_TO_SECONDS = {
    'h': 3600,
    'm': 60,
    's': 1
}

def parse_part(part):
    match = re.match(r'^(\d+)([HhMmSs])$', part)
    if match is None:
        raise ValueError(f'"{part}" is not a valid part of time')
    return (int(match.group(1)),match.group(2).lower() )

def to_seconds_part(part):
    nb, unit = parse_part(part)
    return nb * UNIT_TO_SECONDS[unit]


def to_seconds(user_input):
    parts = user_input.split(':')
    parts_seconds = list(map(to_seconds_part, parts))
    return sum(parts_seconds)
```